# Git Log - merges since last week

Tags: git, merge

If I run this script:

```
git log --since="since last week" I get all commits from last week to now.
```

and if I run

```
git log --merges
```

I get only merges from forever :(

but this returns nil

```
git log --merges --since="since last week"
```

How should I format this to log only merges from last week?

Comment: I'd say you don't have any merge commit since last week (at least on the branch you're executing this from), because the syntax is valid. Maybe compare with "since 7 days"? (which also works)

Comment: Double-check that you're on the relevant branch, or maybe try the same with the `--all` flag to check if this is a branch problem.

Comment: @RomainValeri Thanks for the quick reply. I'm on master and I know there are merges (I've made them) : ). I'll try your troubleshooting tips.

Comment: This worked for me `git log --merges --since=7.days.ago`

Comment: Maybe if you look at the merges without limiting the date it will give you some help? Or change the date to 2 weeks? `git log --pretty="%cd %h" --merges --since-14.days.ago`

Answer (score 0):

> 'm on master and I know there are merges (I've made them)

Considering [`git log --merges`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---merges) only prints commits with at least 2 parents, that means it will print merge commits done on `master`.

But if have merged `master` to other branches, those merge commits won't be listed by a `git log --merges` done on `master`.